# PHP uploads the first TWO images only

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload images to my database, but it's acting really weird, because it uploads the first two images only. I have no idea why the first 2 and not the first only. The code is a little bit long because I'm executing another insert and then inserting the images. It's requested by an AJAX call, don't know if it's important or not. This is how it looks like:

```
if ($ok) {
    //IMAGE UPLOAD
    $filesize_error = 0;
    $filesTempName = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
    $counted = count($filesTempName);
    $allowed_types = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);

    if ($counted > $maxImage) {
        $errorMsg[] = "Maximum 5 képet lehet feltölteni!";
    } else {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
            if (empty($filesTempName[$i])) {
                $errorMsg[] = "Legalább egy képet ki kell választani!";
            } else {
                $detectedType = exif_imagetype($filesTempName[$i]);
                if ($_FILES["images"]["size"][$i] > $maxSize) {
                    $filesize_error = 1;
                    $errorMsg[] = "Minden képnek 2 Mb-nál kisebbnek kell lennie!";
                } elseif (!in_array($detectedType, $allowed_types)) {
                    $errorMsg[] = "A képek csak PNG/JPG/JPEG/GIF formátumban elfogadottak!";
                } elseif ($filesize_error == 0) {

                    if (isset($_POST['mainimage']) && $_POST['mainimage'] != '') {
                        $placeholder = $_POST['mainimage'];
                        $mainimage = 'uploads/' . time() . $placeholder;
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->close();

                        $productid = $link->insert_id;
                        $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO images(thumbnailimage, productid) VALUES(?, ?)");

                        for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
                            $file = $filesTempName[$i];
                            if (is_uploaded_file($file) && !empty($file)) {
                                $data = "uploads/" . time() . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
                                move_uploaded_file($file, $data);

                                $statement->bind_param("si", $data, $productid);
                                $statement->execute();
                            }
                        }
                        $statement->close();
                        $link->close();
                        $success = true;
                        $_SESSION['successad'] = true;
                    } else {
                        $errorMsg[] = "Kérjük válassza ki a fő képet!";
                        $ok = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry if asking obvious thing. Why there are two nested `for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {` loops in the code?

Comment: Hi, that's what I don't understand either, but if I remove the inner for loop, only the first image gets uploaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

count($_FILES["images"]);

try count before temp name, try one var_dump on $_FILES

var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: Thanks for your answer. var_dump helped a lot. The problem was that I missed 'parallelUploads' setting from dropzone.js and it was 2 by default. Changed it to 12 and it works fine.